# Is it possible to access the NSControl on a NSWindow using tag?

Tags: cocoa

Is it possible to access the NSControl on a NSWindow using tag?
I used the code below but it warned

NSWindow may not response to viewWithTag

> NSButton *a=(NSButton * )[self.window
>   viewWithTag:tag];

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `UIWindow` in Cocoa Touch, `NSWindow` does not inherit from `NSView`, and thus does not implement that method. You probably want to get the [contentView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-contentView) of the window, and then look up the tag on that.

Comment: Doesn't help a lot, as you can't set a tag on window's view in interface builder and there's no `setTag` method to use in the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an NSView in your .h file called 'view'.
2. In IB, highlight the View under the Window and connect it to the 'File's Owner' view from step 1.
3. Then you can use viewWithTag.

file.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSView * view;

file.m
[(NSTextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:(1)] setStringValue: @"MyStringName"];